# Secondary namenode stuck while loading INodes

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, garbage-collection, namenode

While starting secondary namenode, it gets stuck while loading Inodes. There are lot of GCs happening on secondary namenode, but its not moving ahead of this that.

```
tstamp_01 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage: 
Transfer took 0.61s at 50920.92 KB/s
tstamp_02 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage: 
Downloaded file edits_tmp_0000000027343051702-
0000000027343328012_0000000040184268530 size 0 bytes.
tstamp_03 INFO 
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImageFormatPBINode: Loading 
309938509 INodes.
```

SNN was set to CMS gc, I also tried changing it to G1GC, but also gc continues with around 99% of time in gcs. Any help on this would be really helpful.

Comment: On namenode "the filesystem checkpoint is 9 hour(s), old". Please also suggest if there is any alternate solution to get latest fsimage on namenode and resetting secondary namenode.